# laravel Page not working when i uploaded my webapp to linux server

Tags: php, linux, laravel, .htaccess

I am getting "Page not working error when to tried to open the URL. I have uploaded my laravel web app to my Linux server provided by godaddy and added .htdocs to that project but when i tried to access the page it says page not working "Internal server error 500" and it is not showing any error.

When I check the networking tab in chrome to see which pages are loading, it is not loading any files but it says the same error 500 internal server error. 
I believe there should be some issue with the .htaccess, it is causing the error but I do not know how to write it for Laravel project.

Below is my .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Deny access to dot files
    RewriteRule (^|/)\.([^/]+)(/|$) - [L,F]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^index.php [L]

    # Redirect non-www to www
    # RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} webappname
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ domainname/webappname/$1 [R,L]

    # Redirect http to https
     RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
   # RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
   # RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: As the error message already tells there is an _internal_ error on the server side. So most likely your scripts crash due to some missconfiguration. The first thing to do in such situations _always_ is to check the http servers error log file. That is most likely where php errors are logged to. So what reason for the error do you read in there?

Comment: I find the below error in log file. please check.

Comment: [28-May-2018 10:10:51 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function Symfony\Polyfill\Mbstring\iconv_strpos() in /vendor/symfony/polyfill-mbstring/Mbstring.php on line 358

Comment: Your php setup does not have the iconv extension installed: http://php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php

Answer (score 0):

Per your last comment, it seems that you're using a PHP version lower than that Laravel needs. What Laravel version are you using and what PHP you have?

Comment: Laravel version is 4.2 and php version installed is 5.6

Comment: Now after updating the php version to 7.0, the error is showing on the webpage where as before it was not showing on the web page.

Comment: create a file with
`<?php phpinfo() ` and see if mbstring and mcrypt appear on the page as enabled.

Comment: mcrypt is enabled but i am not able to see mbstring

Comment: Then you need to install it because it's a Laravel's dependency.